# How do I programmatically assign a on click event to a bullet list which was programmatically created?

Tags: c#

I tried to programtically write a method and assign it as a method called upon a onclick event, but something isn't right here. The method isn't called.

`BulletedList bulletList = new BulletedList();`

I added items into the bullet list using `bulletList.Items.Add(...);`

I tried to programtically assign a bulletList_Click method with `bulletList.Click += new              BulletedListEventHandler(bulletList_Click);`

This is the method which is supposed to be triggered off

> void bulletList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
>   {
>      //codes here
>   }

Comment: Are you using an IDE like VS or writing the code manually?

Comment: Hi I'm using Visual Studio. Also, the BulletList is programmatically created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've created a special class of your own for handling events you're probably just looking for:

<strike>bulletList.Click += new EventHandler(bulletList_Click);</strike>

**Edit:**
You've got your command in there correctly, actually. However, reading your comment above that it is programmatically created, I have an update:

In order to register an event for an object that is programmatically created, the event must be created and added to a control on the page during the `Page_Init` event. If this doesn't happen, the object will not be added to the viewstate and no events will be catchable.

**Edit 2:**
[Here is an article on 4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx) that helped me accomplish this the last time I needed it. [Here is the followup article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx) for it indicating why the Page_Init event is appropriate based on the need to have the control in the ViewState. I have seen elsewhere in other forums that this can be circumvented by making sure that for each postback the controls are added identically to the last time the page was loaded, but I have not verified that functionality.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a `Cannot implicitly convert Type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedListEventHandler'`

Comment: Then use 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedListEventHandler' instead of 'EventHandler', no?

Comment: Yep. I did, take a look at my question above, I used a `BulletedListEventHandler`.

Comment: @csl: I've added an edit based on one of your comments. Your code in the question looks good to me, but likely it simply isn't firing because of when the object is being created.

Comment: Hi, but what happens if the BulletedList is created in other methods other than the `Page_Init` method?

Comment: @Csl: I haven't used this method extensively, so I can't quite remember what got it to work for me the last time I tried it. I will add an edit with a link to a 4Guys From Rolla article that helped me when I did it last.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to have the Event Handler automatically generated from the drag-and-drop interface of Visual Studio? Like selecting the control, selecting the Click event from the events list on the right and then just writing the code inside the generated handler?