# EventHandlers not firing for DropDownList and button

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

A coworker and I can't figure out why the EventHandlers in the following code aren't getting fired. The function is called twice before the first page loads, and AutoPostBack is set to true. The `lnkbtn` button and the `ddlDose` DropDownList are the ones not being fired. It posts back, but it doesn't call the event handler. Here's some code...can anybody see anything inherently wrong?

Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsPostBack)
  {
    tblMedOrdering = (Table)Session["tblMedOrdering"];
    List<string>medNames = (List<string>)Session["medNamesList"];
    populateMeds(medNames); 
  }
}
```

PopulateMeds:

```
protected void populateMeds(List<string> medNames)
{
        if (medNames.Count == 0)
        {
            tblMedOrdering = (Table)Session["tblMedOrdering"];
        }
        else
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string strConn = Application["dbconn"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
            using (SqlCommand medDbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand())
            {
                dbconn.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < medNames.Count; i++)
                {
                    DropDownList ddlDose = new DropDownList();
                    DropDownList ddlSig = new DropDownList();

                    int flag = 0;

                    if ((Table)Session["tblMedOrdering"] != null)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < tblMedOrdering.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (tblMedOrdering.Rows[j].Cells[3].Text == medNames[i].ToString())
                            {
                                flag = 1;
                                ddlSig = (DropDownList)tblMedOrdering.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl(medNames[i].ToString() + "ddlSig");
                                if (ddlSig == null)
                                {
                                    ddlSig.ID = medNames[i].ToString() + "ddlSig";
                                    ListItem liDefaultSig = new ListItem();
                                    liDefaultSig.Value = "0";
                                    liDefaultSig.Text = "Select . . .";
                                    ddlSig.Items.Add(liDefaultSig);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (flag != 1)
                    {
                        ListItem liDefault = new ListItem();
                        liDefault.Value = "0";
                        liDefault.Text = "Select . . .";

                        ddlDose.Items.Add(liDefault);
                        ddlSig.Items.Add(liDefault);

                        ddlDose.ID = medNames[i].ToString() + "ddlDose";
                        ddlSig.ID = medNames[i].ToString() + "ddlSig";

                        ddlDose.AutoPostBack = true;

                        ddlDose.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ddlDose_SelectedIndexChanged);

                        medDbcmd.CommandText = "Select distinct medorderid, dose from ordertablemeds where medordername = '" + medNames[i].ToString() + "'";

                        SqlDataReader dr = medDbcmd.ExecuteReader();

                        if (dr != null)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                ListItem liDose = new ListItem();

                                liDose.Value = dr["medorderid"].ToString();
                                liDose.Text = dr["dose"].ToString();

                                ddlDose.Items.Add(liDose);
                            }
                            dr.Close();
                        }

                        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                        tr.ID = medNames[i].ToString() + "TableRow";

                        TableCell tcDose = new TableCell();
                        TableCell tcSig = new TableCell();
                        TableCell tcRemove = new TableCell();
                        TableCell tcMedName = new TableCell();


                        tcDose.Controls.Add(ddlDose);

                        tcSig.Controls.Add(ddlSig);
                        tcMedName.Text = medNames[i].ToString();
                        tcMedName.ID = medNames[i].ToString() + "medname";

                        LinkButton lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn.Text = "X";
                        lnkbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lnkbtn.ID = medNames[i].ToString() + "_lnkbtn" + tblMedOrdering.Rows.Count;
                        lnkbtn.Click += new EventHandler(Reset_Click);

                        tcRemove.Controls.Add(lnkbtn);

                        tr.Cells.Add(tcRemove);
                        tr.Cells.Add(tcDose);
                        tr.Cells.Add(tcSig);
                        tr.Cells.Add(tcMedName);

                        tblMedOrdering.Rows.Add(tr);

                    }
                }
                tblMedOrdering.DataBind();
                dbconn.Close();
            }
        }

        Session["tblMedOrdering"] = tblMedOrdering;

        if (medNames.Count == 0)
        {
            cpeMeds.Collapsed = true;
            cpeMeds.ClientState = "True";
        }

        List<string> medNamesList = new List<string>();
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        for (int k = 0; k < tblMedOrdering.Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            ddl = (DropDownList)tblMedOrdering.Rows[k].Cells[1].FindControl(tblMedOrdering.Rows[k].Cells[3].Text +"ddlDose");
            ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlDose_SelectedIndexChanged);
            medNamesList.Add(tblMedOrdering.Rows[k].Cells[3].Text);
        }
        Session["medNamesList"] = medNamesList;
    }
```

PopulateMeds is just a function that gets called in the code-behind and is given a list of string names, so it doesn't need args as if it were a control (objects sender, EventArgs e).

Comment: Try binding your controls in OnInit() instead of Page_Load(). Also, learn the ASP.NET Page Life Cylce - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.

Comment: This is not a purely duplicate question, so I won't vote to close, but the articles in my answer to the attached question might provide some insight. The controls you're adding aren't being added soon enough to be added to the ViewState (thus your events aren't being truly wired up)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050652/how-do-i-programmatically-assign-a-on-click-event-to-a-bullet-list-which-was-pro/8050691#8050691

Comment: @Joel Definitely interested in that link. I looked at a ton of recommended related links before posting, but that wasn't one of them and none of them were really relevant/helpful.

Comment: @jrummell Trying your suggestion now. And thanks for the reference link btw... I guess it's pretty obvious how new I am to ASP.NET

Comment: No problem. Just about everyone new to ASP.NET will run into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move that logic to `OnInit` and the event handlers should function properly, assuming that everything else is correct. I would also check to make sure that you don't have validation interfering with the postback.